# The central point of graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'm having some trouble thinking about how to locate the central point of a graph; that is, a node on a graph which minimizes the maximal distance to all the other ones.

For example:

Lets say I have a graph with 3 nodes, arranged in a line (like `1-2-3`).

Obviously, it's easy to see that the central point of this graph is `2`. How would I get around to implementing something like that though?

The only algorithms that I know is BFS/DFS/Prim's/ and Kruskal's. Prim's and Kruskal's algorithms don't really apply in this case. I'm thinking that I need to use BFS here? The only issue is, doesn't BFS return a different order depending on which node you start at?

Comment: Is that `minimizes the average distance` or `maximum distance` or something else?

Comment: It should be minimizes the maximum distance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For rather dense graphs:

1. Build all shortest paths matrix with [Floyd-Warshall algorthm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm)
2. Find maximum value in each line - this is eccentricity of corresponding vertice (node)
3. Choose vertices with minimal eccentricity - they are central nodes (and minimal eccentricity is graph radius)

complexity O(V^3) (with small constants)

If graph is sparse, you can use BFS from each vertice or [Johnson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm)

(O(V^2+ V*E), O(V^2*logV + V*E))

FYE:

```
0 1 2   //ecc = 2
1 0 1   //ecc = 1 - central point
2 1 0   //ecc = 2
```

If you work with tree (as MST has been mentioned in vanished comment) - there is faster method:

1. one BFS from any vertice
2. another BFS from the farthest vertice found
3. get middle vertice(s) in the longest path of the second BFS

O(V + E)

Comment: If graph is sparse, you can use BFS from each vertice or Johnson's algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson's_algorithm

Comment: If you work with tree - there is faster method: one BFS from any vertice, another BFS from the farthest vertice found, and get median vertice(s) in order of the second BFS

Comment: It is not easy to hold a dialogue with vanishing comments ;)

Comment: haha sorry, i'm in the middle of typing them, then you reply with a pretty good answer! But it looks like BFS should do for now, I forgot to mention that the graph that I have is (co-incidentally) a MST

Answer (score 0):

The Python module **NetworkX** provide such API [`center(G, e=None)`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.distance_measures.center.html). Refer to its source code [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/algorithms/distance_measures.html#center) for the implementation.

Take the Florentine families graph as an example, the center nodes are colored in red.

[image]

---

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.florentine_families_graph()
center_nodes = nx.center(G)
```