# Find the node with the minimum maximum distance in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, undirected-graph

I have an undirected, unweighted graph and I want to find the node that has the smallest maximum distance to the other nodes in the graph. Pretty much, I just want to find the center of the graph.

I tried an O(N*(N+E)) approach by finding the maximum distance from every single node, and then taking the smallest one. I was wondering if there is any algorithm faster than O(N*(N+E)) to do this job.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The central point of graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674976/the-central-point-of-graph)

Comment: any weighted graph solution will work for an unweighted graph; just set the weights to 1.

Comment: Btw is this really a theory question, or do you have actual code and data and it's too slow? If the latter, it's possible that the code is bad, for example you wouldn't be the first person to add an extra factor N to their complexity by using the wrong data structure. Also, if this is indeed a theory question, you might actually be on the wrong site.

Answer (score 1):

You could run BFS from all nodes in parallel, one depth at a time. Then you can stop when one BFS finishes and don't need to finish the others. Still O(N*(N+E)) but might be faster, depending on your data.